# Indian Timezone behind by 40 minutes in default php timezone setting

Tags: php

I am trying to use "`Asia/Kolkata`" as default Timezone for my sitewide PHP script, but the time that is being displayed is 40 minutes behind the original time. How can I fix this?

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
```

Expected Result on using `format('d M Y, h:m A')`: `19 Jun 2019, 12:54 PM`

Actual Result: `19 Jun 2019, 12:14 PM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `format('d M Y, h:i A')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo date('d M Y, h:m A');
```

Shows the correct output